# Prevent to submit page when refreshing page using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I force refresh a page using javascript? But without resubmitting the form or prevent the confirmation message that says resending the information I previously submitted.

[image: refresh]

I need to accomplish this to prevent double entry of records.
Thanks in advance.

I'm using window.location.reload()

Comment: You should post your full submit code. What language are you submitting to? How are you processing the post data?

Comment: I'm using ASP. There is an alert message before form submission, that's why I cannot use ASP to reload the page or else the alert message does not show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force change method to get by using `window.location.reload(true)` or `window.location.href = window.location.href`.

Comment: window.location.href = window.location.href did work. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Your previous page was the result of a POST action.

The best practice is to do an HTTP 302 redirect after the post to a "clean" URL (eg a GET).

This ensures that the post action isn't performed twice accidentally and the warning goes away.